# ucfirst() not working properly with scandinavic characters

Tags: php, string, special-characters, ucfirst

How to get `ucfirst()` working with scandinavic characters?

```
$str = "SÄKYLÄ";
echo ucfirst(strtolower($str)); //prints SÄkylÄ
```

One possibility is use `mb_convert_case()` but I'd like to know if this is possible using `ucfirst()`

```
$str = "SÄKYLÄ";
echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8"); //prints Säkylä
```

Which function is faster for string capitalization?

Comment: According to PHP's `ucfirst` documentation: `in the default "C" locale characters such as umlaut-a (ä) will not be converted.`. So I think you need to run `setlocale()` first: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is not `ucfirst()` it's `strtolower()`. You have to use [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php), to get your string in lower case, e.g.

```
echo ucfirst(mb_strtolower($str));
           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
```

Also you can find a multibyte version of `ucfirst()` in the [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php#57298) from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php):

> Simple multi-bytes ucfirst():
>
> ```
> <?php
>
>    function my_mb_ucfirst($str) {
>        $fc = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1));
>        return $fc.mb_substr($str, 1);
>    }
> ```

<sub>Code from plemieux from the manual [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php#57298)</sub>